# At least apostrophes now do not always preview correctly when an internal link is used

Tags: bug, markdown-preview, internal-links

> [image]
> Link to [submitted post](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52239/32596)

I [searched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarkdown-preview%5D%20apostrophe%20created%3A..2021-5-19) and I do not think it was reported.

When an internal link is used, *at least* (possibly other characters are impacted) apostrophes now do not* render properly in the preview (they used to) – the final result after submitting is correct though.

* Edit: for some reason I cannot repro.

Comment: can't reproduce either

Comment: No repro: Firefox 88.0.1 64 bit, on win 10. Also no repro: Chrome 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (64-bit), win 10.

Comment: I can no longer repro as the title has changed. Using this link: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/11721 (credits go to HNQ) I also fail to repro, using FF on macOS

Comment: Mmm... Given that this seems to be a transient issue, I've gotta vote to close this as no longer reproducible. I'll follow this question and, if you see it happen again, go ahead and include another screenshot/update the post and I'll help vote to reopen.